# Create db Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is my error with explanations please, need to create a table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RetrieveEntityParent] (@FK_EntityId int (max))

   with p as
    (SELECT     EntityId, FK_ParentId , EntityName ,EntityArabicName 
     FROM         OrgEntity
     WHERE OrgEntity.EntityId=14 

   UNION ALL      
    SELECT       PA.EntityId, PA.FK_ParentId, PA.EntityName,PA.EntityArabicName 
    FROM         OrgEntity as PA 
    inner join p
    ON p.FK_ParentId = PA.EntityId)


   SELECT * from p
```

Comment: what error has been thrown when you try to execute that?

Comment: @JW.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure RetrieveEntityParent, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure RetrieveEntityParent, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for an [inline table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175924%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RetrieveEntityParent] (@FK_EntityId int (max))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    ... your query here ...
```

Comment: Error on excution
Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RetrieveEntityParent, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

Comment: i`ve changed the type to varchar and it worked, need explanation please if you may.
(@FK_EntityId varchar (max))

Comment: Right, `int (max)` doesn't exist!   Use `int` instead.

Comment: Ask a new question with sample code and the error message. A working demo at sqlfiddle.com is always appreciated.